# Python code refactor to use multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have written some Python code that opens files one by one, does some work, and writes data onto the filesystem. I figured, I want to make use of my cores.I've refactored the program into this.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import glob

def work(file_name):
    # do work
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(work, (glob.iglob('.somedir/**/*.data', recursive=True)))
    pool.close()
```

Wanted to know if that's okay practice.

Comment: I think your copy and paste did not work (`passif `)

Comment: `# do work` This question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## context manager

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) uses a `with` statement, instead of

```
pool = Pool()
...
pool.close()
```

to make sure the `close` is run, even when there are exceptions

## variables

Variables names are the primary means of commenting you code. I would make `glob.iglob('.somedir/**/*.data', recursive=True))` a variable. I would even use the `pathlib` module to make the code even more clear.

This also gives you the opportunity to test whether the `glob` gives you back the correct files.

## type annotations

You can tell the functions which types it can expect.This does nothing at run-time, but can help your IDE detect small bugs, and act as additional documentation to the users of the function

## programming tools

I use [`black`](https://github.com/psf/black) as code formatter, [`isort`](https://isort.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to sort my imports, a linter [`pylama`](https://github.com/klen/pylama)  and [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) for static code analysis. All integrated into my IDE workflow.

For mypy, I use this rather strict configuration

```
[mypy]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_any_generics = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
no_implicit_optional = true
warn_redundant_casts = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
```

---

```
import typing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pathlib import Path


def work(file_name: typing.Union[str, Path]) -> None:
    """<doc-string>"""
    # do work
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_dir = Path(".somedir/")
    file_names = data_dir.glob("**/*.data")
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(work, file_names)
```